# use of '+' - addition or concatenation

Tags: java, concatenation

Code Snippet 1:

```
    Long [] a1 = {3L,4L,5L};
    System.out.print(a1[0].toString() + a1[1] + a1[2]);
```

//Output: 345

Code Snippet 2:

```
    Long [] a1 = {3L,4L,5L};
    System.out.print(a1[0] + a1[1] + a1[2] + " ");
```

//Output: 12

In Snippet 1, we have '+' is used as addition so we have 3+4+5 = 12
However, using same logic, in Snippet 2, why we don't have 37 rather than 345

Comment: I think you mixed up your snippets.

Comment: Yes, in the first one you get 345 and in the second one you get 12

Comment: Consider correcting your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression passed to `print` is evaluated from left to right. If the first expression inside the `print` statement is a String, the `+` operator will be treated as String concatenation. If the first expression is numeric, the `+` operator will be treated as addition.

BTW, unlike what you wrote in the question, the first snippet is the one that outputs 345, due to String concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Java evaluate expression **Left to Right**

In your case `System.out.print(a1[0] + a1[1] + a1[2] + " ")`  It first evaluate `""` it is string then it concat `""` with `a1[2]` value and so on... that why you get that output  `345` ***it is not addition it is concatenation of string.***